# Mule persistent OAuth token store

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule

Does anyone know how to configure a persistent token store for Mule OAuth Provider module?
Adding a normal object store does not support the `org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore` interface.

**EDIT**

I want to persist to file - disk.

**EDIT 2**

Flow with OAuth provider setup:

```
<mule xmlns:objectstore="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
    xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
    xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
    xmlns:oauth2-provider="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2-provider"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2-provider http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2-provider/current/mule-oauth2-provider.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/current/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore/current/mule-objectstore.xsd">
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="oauthTokenStore" name="oauthTokenStore" class="org.mule.util.store.TextFileObjectStore"/>
    </spring:beans>

    <spring:beans>
        <ss:authentication-manager id="resourceOwnerAuthenticationManager">
            <ss:authentication-provider>
                <ss:user-service id="resourceOwnerUserService">
                    <ss:user name="${username}" password="${password}" authorities="RESOURCE_OWNER" />
                </ss:user-service>
            </ss:authentication-provider>
        </ss:authentication-manager>
    </spring:beans>

    <mule-ss:security-manager>
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="resourceOwnerSecurityProvider" delegate-ref="resourceOwnerAuthenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>

    <oauth2-provider:config name="blazeOauth2Provider"
        providerName="Blaze" host="0.0.0.0" port="${blaze.esb.port.https}"
        authorizationEndpointPath="api/1.0/authorize" accessTokenEndpointPath="api/1.0/token"
        resourceOwnerSecurityProvider-ref="resourceOwnerSecurityProvider"
        scopes="BLAH" doc:name="OAuth provider module"
        tokenTtlSeconds="${blaze.security.token.lifespan}" connector-ref="httpsServerConnector" supportedGrantTypes="AUTHORIZATION_CODE IMPLICIT" enableRefreshToken="true" tokenStore-ref="oauthTokenStore" >

        <oauth2-provider:clients>
            <oauth2-provider:client clientId="${blaze.client.id}" secret="${blaze.client.secret}" type="CONFIDENTIAL" clientName="Client" description="Service Front-End">
                <oauth2-provider:redirect-uris>
                    <oauth2-provider:redirect-uri>http://localhost*</oauth2-provider:redirect-uri>
                </oauth2-provider:redirect-uris>
                <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-types>
                    <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>AUTHORIZATION_CODE</oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>
                    <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>TOKEN</oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>
                </oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-types>
                <oauth2-provider:scopes>
                    <oauth2-provider:scope>BLAH</oauth2-provider:scope>
                </oauth2-provider:scopes>
            </oauth2-provider:client>
        </oauth2-provider:clients>
    </oauth2-provider:config>

</mule>
```

Comment: What type of persistence wants to use to storing the tokens?

Comment: File persistence - I've edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Julio answer:

Added a class, that implements a map `<String, AccessTokenStoreHolder>`:

```
package xxx;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException;
import org.mule.api.store.ObjectDoesNotExistException;
import org.mule.api.store.ObjectStoreException;
import org.mule.config.i18n.CoreMessages;
import org.mule.util.FileUtils;
import org.mule.util.IOUtils;
import org.mule.util.StringUtils;
import org.mule.util.store.InMemoryObjectStore;
import org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.AccessTokenStoreHolder;

public class PersistantOAuthObjectStore extends InMemoryObjectStore<AccessTokenStoreHolder> {

    protected File fileStore;
    protected String directory;
    private Map<String, AccessTokenStoreHolder> tokenStore;
    private FileOutputStream output;

    public PersistantOAuthObjectStore() {
        super();
    }

    private Map<String, AccessTokenStoreHolder> getTokenStore() {
        if (tokenStore == null)
            tokenStore = new HashMap<>();
        return tokenStore;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialise() throws InitialisationException
    {
        super.initialise();
         if (directory == null)
            directory = context.getConfiguration().getWorkingDirectory() + "/objectstore";

        try
        {
            File dir = FileUtils.openDirectory(directory);
            fileStore = new File(dir, name + ".dat");
            if (fileStore.exists())
                loadFromStore();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InitialisationException(e, this);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected synchronized void loadFromStore() throws Exception
    {
        ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileStore));
        Object result = stream.readObject();
        tokenStore = (Map<String, AccessTokenStoreHolder>)result;
        for (Map.Entry<String, AccessTokenStoreHolder> entry : getTokenStore().entrySet())
            super.store(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue());

        stream.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void store(Serializable id, AccessTokenStoreHolder item) throws ObjectStoreException
    {
        super.store(id, item);

        try
        {

            synchronized(getTokenStore()) {
                getTokenStore().put(id.toString(), item);
                saveMap();
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new ObjectStoreException(e);
        }
    }

    private void saveMap() throws IOException {
        if (output == null)
            output = new FileOutputStream(fileStore, false);

        ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(output); 
        stream.writeObject(getTokenStore());
    }

    @Override
    public AccessTokenStoreHolder remove(Serializable key) throws ObjectStoreException
    {
        super.retrieve(key);

        try
        {
            synchronized (getTokenStore())
            {
                if (getTokenStore().containsKey(key)) {
                    AccessTokenStoreHolder val = getTokenStore().get(key);
                    getTokenStore().remove(key);
                    saveMap();
                    return val;
                }
            }

            throw new ObjectDoesNotExistException(CoreMessages.objectNotFound(key));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new ObjectStoreException(e);
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public void clear() throws ObjectStoreException
    {
        super.clear();

        try
        {
            synchronized (getTokenStore()) {
                getTokenStore().clear();
                saveMap();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new ObjectStoreException(e);
        }
    }

    public String getDirectory()
    {
        return directory;
    }

    public void setDirectory(String directory)
    {
        this.directory = directory;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPersistent() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then add 2 spring beans to xml:

```
<spring:bean id="oauthTokenStore" name="oauthTokenStore" class="org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.ObjectStoreTokenStore">
    <spring:property name="accessTokenObjectStore" ref="oauthObjectStore"/>
</spring:bean>
<spring:bean id="oauthObjectStore" class="com.vatit.blaze.esb.utils.objectStore.BlazePersistantObjectStore" init-method="initialise" destroy-method="dispose" name="oauthObjectStore">
    <spring:property name="name" value="oauthObjectStore"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Then ref the **tokenStore** in your OAuth 2 provider config:
`tokenStore-ref="oauthTokenStore"`

Comment: re-posted with some junk cleaned out + fixed sync sections - i think (java beginner)

Answer (score 1):

ok, after performing a simple test, I recommend developing your own FileObjectStore for more control.

1. Create public class, for example:

   public class MyFileObjectStore  extends AbstractObjectStore  { ..}
2. Use a properties file to store the token, key=value
3. Implement the methods: doStore, doRetrieve, doRemove, basically to update on a properties files.
4. Change in you flow:

   ```
   <spring:bean id="accessTokenStore" class="test.MyFileObjectStore"/>

   <spring: bean name="tokenStore" class="org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.ObjectStoreTokenStore">
   <spring:property name="accessTokenObjectStore" ref="accessTokenStore" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to set the tokenStore for oauth. You can use for example (the most common):

1. org.mule.util.store.PartitionedPersistentObjectStore or
2. org.mule.transport.jdbc.store.JdbcObjectStore

For your requirement, you can use:

**org.mule.util.store.TextFileObjectStore**

I hope to help;

Comment: Thanks Julio, do you have an example - i'm struggling to implement. Tried `<spring:bean id="oauthTokenStore" name="oauthTokenStore" class="org.mule.util.store.TextFileObjectStore"/>` and linking that to the OAuth token store ref, but Mule doesn't like: cannot convert to type `org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore`

Comment: added EDIT 2 - XML with global provider

Answer (score 0):

I think the above answers are correct but not ideal. `ObjectStoreTokenStore` can be composed of multiple persistent object stores. I am not sure if you even need to write any Java code to have this done.

```
<spring:bean name="tokenStore" class="org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.ObjectStoreTokenStore">
    <spring:property name="accessTokenObjectStore" ref="accessTokenFileObjectStore"/>
    <spring:property name="refreshTokenObjectStore" ref="refreshTokenFileObjectStore"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Here `accessTokenFileObjectStore` and `refreshTokenFileObjectStore` can be spring beans created out from `TextFileObjectStore`